# On DynamoDB, can client specify timestamp to determine the most recent update such that most recent data always is persisted in the table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

In case of using DynamoDB as event db and events arriving out of order, how can I ensure that data persisted in the table is always the latest.
For example,

Table_a has a customer record that was updated on Feb 15, 2020. If a delayed event comes through with an updated date of Feb 14, 2020; I do not want to update the table. Doing a read and determining on a service could turn this into a costlier operation, so want to avoid that too. Looking for a solution where DynamoDB can internally handle this.

On Cassandra, this is possible as the client can provide the timestamp to determine the most recent update to a column. Wondering if DynamoDB supports this.

Comment: This is going to depend on how your date is stored.  What does your table look like?  What are you using as your primary key?  Are you using a sort key?

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB supports conditional updates:

> To perform a conditional update, you use an UpdateItem operation with a condition expression. The condition expression must evaluate to true in order for the operation to succeed; otherwise, the operation fails.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html#Expressions.ConditionExpressions.SimpleComparisons

The expression should be something like `LastModified < :dateFromEvent`.